# I am using BigINT in MySQL and I want to retrieve it in android using Shared Preferences so how to do it?

Tags: android, mysql, sharedpreferences

I am using Mobile number in Big INT MySQL and I want to retrieve it in Shared Preferences but there is no datatype for big int in its editor.

Comment: If "Mobile number" means a phone number, you shouldn't be handling that as a numeric type. Treat it as text.

Comment: I converted phone number in text but still I am not getting it as String in sharedpreferences

Comment: i am getting a error of Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: try this `String.valueOf(longvalofphone number);`n than store in shared pref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this

```
public static void loadI() {
    i = new BigInteger(prefs.getString("I", "0"));
}

public static void saveI() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("I", i.toString());
    editor.apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this treat you big int as a string or text in `SharedPreferences` than 
 **you can store phone number in Shared Preferences as text or string like this**

```
  SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
  sharedpreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("phone", MODE_PRIVATE); 
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
  editor.putString("number",String.valueOf(1234567890););
  editor.commit();
```